# Determining the byte size of a scipy.sparse.lil_matrix

Tags: python, matrix, size, sparse-matrix

I've tried numerous approaches to measure the size of my scipy.sparse.lil_matrix object in python to no avail.

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

# Build the matrix: 
sparse_lil = lil_matrix((4, 4), dtype=np.int32)

# measure size
sparse_lil[1, 1] = 1

# measure size again
sparse_lil[2, 2] = 2

# measure size again
sparse_lil[3, 3] = 3

# measure size again
sparse_lil[4, 4] = 4
```

Here are the options I've tried- all fail to detect any difference in byte size after the addition of each new number to the matrix.

```
# 1
import sys
sys.getsizeof(sparse_lil)

# 2
from pympler import asizeof
asizeof.asizeof(sparse_lil)

# 3
sparse_lil.data.nbytes
```

I think the list of list format will probably require a unique approach, but this is not something I typically have to do, so am not sure where to start.

Greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Why do you need this?  What's the nature of the 2 main attributes that hold data and indices?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the size is because this data structure is absolutely worthless and you should not use it for any reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at a simple lil:

```
In [54]: from scipy import sparse

In [55]: M=sparse.lil_matrix([[1,0,3],[3,0,0],[0,0,1]])
In [56]: M
Out[56]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 4 stored elements in List of Lists format>
```

And the 2 main attributes:

```
In [57]: M.data
Out[57]: array([list([1, 3]), list([3]), list([1])], dtype=object)    
In [58]: M.rows
Out[58]: array([list([0, 2]), list([0]), list([2])], dtype=object)
```

It's well known that `getsize` is not a good 'size' tool for lists. And an object dtype array has the same issue.  We can get the `nbytes` of each array, but that's just the size of the databuffer that holds references to the element lists.  The shape of both arrays is the number of rows of the matrix.  `M.nnz` is 4 the total number of nonzero terms.

```
In [60]: M.data.nbytes   # 3*8
Out[60]: 24
```

`getsizeof` of a list tells us the bytes in its array of pointers, but not the size of the elements pointed to.  `nnz*8` roughly is the number of pointers - though lists have some 'headroom' for growth.

It looks like the individual values in the `data` lists are python float or int.  I can't force them to be `int32` or other numpy dtype.  `M.dtype` must be operating at a higher level, when returning individual values.

`sys.getsizeof` of a python int is 28, and 24 for a float.  Though the int size can vary - for very large ints.  And small ints, under 255, are 'cached' so don't take up any extra space.

So a rough estimate of the memory usage of the `data` attribute is:

```
In [73]: sys.getsizeof(M.data), sum([sys.getsizeof(i) for i in M.data]),M.nnz*sys.getsizeof(M.data[0][0])
Out[73]: (136, 200, 112)
In [74]: sum(_)
Out[74]: 448
```

`rows` should be similar, so something in the 900-1000 bytes size for this (3,3) with 4 nnz.

I was going to test this against the `save_nnz` file size, but that save is not implemented for `lil` format.

`lil` is designed for ease of setting values as you do - one by one.   Low memory use, or math, or file storage are not its intended uses.

Contrast this with `coo`:

```
In [78]: Mo=M.tocoo()
In [79]: Mo
Out[79]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

bytes in the 3 attribute arrays:

```
In [80]: Mo.data.nbytes+Mo.row.nbytes+Mo.col.nbytes
Out[80]: 48    
In [81]: Mo.data
Out[81]: array([1, 3, 3, 1], dtype=int32)    
In [82]: Mo.row
Out[82]: array([0, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

But each array has an overhead, which is significant for arrays this small:

```
In [87]: [sys.getsizeof(i) for i in [Mo.data,Mo.row,Mo.col]]
Out[87]: [112, 128, 112]    
In [88]: sum(_)
Out[88]: 352
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. Greatly appreciate the alternative option/comparison as well.